# How to get the value of an interface property to influence the type of a parameter in a callback of the same interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

Apologies, I wasn't sure exactly how to phrase this question because I don't know enough about typescript generics. However I do have an example demonstrating my issue:

```
import React from 'react';

type DataType = Record<string, string | number | Date>;

const data: { a: string, b: number, c: Date }[] = [{ a: 'hello', b: 10, c: new Date() }, { a: 'bye', b: 20, c: new Date() }, { a: 'good', b: 30, c: new Date() }];

interface Bar<T extends DataType, K extends keyof T> {
  name: K;
  callback: (value: T[K]) => void
}

interface Foo<T extends DataType, K extends keyof T> {
  data: T[]
  bar: Bar<T, K>[]
}

function MyComponent<T extends DataType, K extends keyof T>({
  data,
  bar
}: Foo<T, K>) {
  console.log(data);
  console.log(bar)
  return <div />
}

export function ExampleApp() {

  return (
    <MyComponent
      data={data}
      bar={[
        {
          name: 'a',
          callback: (value) => console.log(value) // value has type string | number | Date
        },
        {
          name: 'b',
          callback: (value) => console.log(value) // value has type string | number | Date
        },
        {
          name: 'c',
          callback: (value) => console.log(value) // value has type string | number | Date
        },
      ]}
    />
  );
}
```

My question is, how can I get the `value` parameter of `callback` in `bar` to be the type of the value of the item with key `<name>` in `data`? Each `value` parameter currently type `string | number | Date` but I would like it so that it picks up the type from the items in `data`:

```
{
  name: 'a',
  callback: (value) => console.log(value) // value has type string
},
{
  name: 'b',
  callback: (value) => console.log(value) // value has type number
},
{
  name: 'c',
  callback: (value) => console.log(value) // value has type Date
},
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/m0LLxm) work for you?

Comment: @aleksxor That worked perfectly! Think you could provide an ELI5 of what's going on there?

Comment: I'll try to do a thorough explanations why your type doesn't work as it should and this one works as desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataType` is overly vague type and you cannot infer `key-value` type correspondence from it at all. The only thing it says that object having this type has *only* string keys and values *only* of types `string`, `number` and `Date`.

But even if you replace `Record` with a well defined type:

```ts
type Obj = { a: string, b: number, c: Date }
```

`Bar` still won't work as expected.

```ts
interface Bar<T, K extends keyof T = keyof T> {
  name: K;
  callback: (value: T[K]) => void
}
```

The issue is the `K` type is a union here. If we substitute `K` with it's concrete type value:`'a' | 'b' | 'c'` we get the following:

```ts
/*
type BarResult = {
    name: keyof Obj; // 'a' | 'b' | 'c'
    callback: (value: string | number | Date) => void;
}
*/
type BarResult = Bar<Obj>
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/N7ggGN)

As you can notice there is no one-to-one correspondence here. The `name` property can be any of the keys and the `callback` property shoud be a function accepting a parameter of pretty strange union type.

To make it work as intended we're going to use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html):

```ts
type MiddleBar<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: { name: K; callback: (value: T[K]) => void }
}

type MiddleResult = Bar<Obj>
```

Here we're iterating over `keyof Obj` values and assigning to each of the keys `a` | `b` | `c` corresponding object. Substitute `T` for the `Obj` and keys for each of the available values. For example for the key `a` inside the external curly brackets we'll get:

```ts
    ['a']: { name: 'a', callback: (value: Obj['a']) => void // Obj['a'] == string
```

Full `MiddleResult` type will look like:

```ts
/*
type MiddleResult = {
    a: {
        name: "a";
        callback: (value: string) => void;
    };
    b: {
        name: "b";
        callback: (value: number) => void;
    };
    c: {
        name: "c";
        callback: (value: Date) => void;
    };
}
*/
type MiddleResult = MiddleBar<Obj>
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NrvvoN)

Almost there. We definitely see the types we need inside. The only step left to use [lookup type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) to get the result union. When we use lookup by a union type we get union of values corresponding to the keys of that union. Simple example:

```ts
type A = { s: string, n: number }

type B = A['s'] // string
type C = A['n'] // number
type D = A['s' | 'n'] // = A['s'] | A['n'] = string | number
```

Making the final step and doing lookup by all keys of the `T` object ([keyof T](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#the-keyof-type-operator)):

```ts
type Obj = { a: string, b: number, c: Date }

type Bar<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: { name: K; callback: (value: T[K]) => void }
}[keyof T]

/*
type Result = {
    name: "a";
    callback: (value: string) => void;
} | {
    name: "b";
    callback: (value: number) => void;
} | {
    name: "c";
    callback: (value: Date) => void;
}
*/
type Result = Bar<Obj>
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/N9JJ7m)

Comment: That's really impressive! Tried to answer this interesting question myself and wasn't manage to get to this great solution even though it makes a lot of sense. You have a great understanding of the amazing features of TS. Well done.

Comment: @RonRofe Couldn't have said it better myself. It was an awesome explanation!

Comment: @aleksxor I haven't done much reading on mapped types so thanks for the introduction!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I'm not sure if you can have different return types in the callback function, I think it might not be possible though someone else can correct me if I'm wrong.

One solution though is type checking after you get the value from the callback function:

```
const value = exampleFunction()
// value has type string | number | Date
if (typeof value === "string") {
    // Now value has type string
}
```